# Can you specify an object literal's type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify an object literal's type.

For example, how would one resolve this code and assign a `B` literal to an `A` variable:

```js
interface A {
    a: string;
}

interface B extends A {
    b: string
}

const a: A = {
    a: "",
    b: ""
};
```

`B` is an `A`, so I expect to be able to assign a `B` where an `A` is expected. However, the compiler does not have enough context to figure out that I am passing a `B` as opposed to an illegal `A`, so I need to specify it.

I don't want to just make the above code compile, I specifically want my intent of "I am assigning a `B` to an `A`" to be conveyed to the compiler. I want the type safety of having a `B` object literal, so if `B` gets additional properties for example, this should fail to compile again.

I stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456105/how-can-i-specify-a-typed-object-literal-in-typescript) when searching for this. One option is to define an identity function as such:

```js
const is = <T>(x: T): T => x;

const a: A = is<B>({
    a: "",
    b: ""
});
```

This is not ideal as it will run code for the sake of something that is irrelevant after transpiling. Another option is to use a second variable as such:

```js
const b: B = {
    a: "",
    b: ""
};

const a: A = b;
```

Also not ideal for the same reason, it's code for the sake of a TypeScript check.

@jcalz's proposals:

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
  [k: string]: unknown; // any other property is fine
}
```

This allows any excess properties to pass, when I just want `A` and its subtypes to pass. `A`'s closedness is not the problem, I'm just unable to tell the compiler that I am passing a `B` where an `A` is expected.

```
Turn off --suppressExcessPropertyErrors compiler option
```

I want to suppress excess properties, the problem is that I'm unable to tell the compiler that these aren't excess properties, they are the properties of a proper subtype.

Is there an equivalent to type declarations for literals? Is there a fundamental design of TypeScript that prevents such a construct from existing?

In a language such as Kotlin, this is trivial:

```
val a: A = B()
```

You can separately declare the type of the variable and the type of the runtime object (must be the same type or a subtype).

In case this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), the problem I was originally trying to solve looks like this:

```js
const foo = (): A => {
    if (/* condition */) {
        /* some setup.. */
        return {
            a: "",
            b: ""
        }
    } else {
        return {
            a: ""
        }
    }
}
```

This does not compile because the first `return` is not explicitly an `A`, it is intended to be a `B` which *is* an `A`, but I have no way of specifying it as a `B` without resorting to one of the workarounds I mentioned above. I want something that looks like

```js
return {
    a: "",
    b: ""
}: B

// or

return: B {
    a: "",
    b: ""
}

// or

return {
    a: "",
    b: ""
} is B
```

It goes without saying that `as B` type assertions are not what I'm looking for here. I don't want to bypass the type system, I just want to help the compiler check my object literal as a specified type. This problem also applies to parameters:

```js
const foo = (a: A) => {};

foo({ a: "", b: "" })
```

This fails, because I have no way of telling the compiler that I am passing a `B`, it thinks I am using excess properties. It only works if I use an extra variable like so:

```js
const b: B = { a: "", b: "" };

foo(b)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you want to write `const a: B = ...` if you want to make sure it is a `B`? You can still use that variable anywhere an `A` is expected.

Comment: @IngoBürk It's a contrived example to illustrate my point of wanting an expression to be a subtype of an expected type. Replace `const` with `let`, and assume I have a second subtype `C`. I should be able to assign a `B` followed by a `C`, since they are both `A`s, but if I had written `let a: B = ...` this would not be possible. I don't want to make sure `a` is a `B`, I want `a` to be an `A` but allowed to hold a `B` or `C` literal.

Comment: "This allows any literal to pass as an `A`, when I just want `A` and its subtypes to pass." That's not true; `{foo: "bar"}` will not pass as it's missing the `a` property. `{a: 123}` will not pass, as the `a` property is the wrong type. `{a: "", b:"", c: "", d: ""}` *will* pass because it is a subtype of `A`. Maybe the confusion here is that TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and not nominal. Had you defined `interface B {a:string; b:string}`; the compiler would know it extends `A` anyway, due to the structure.

Comment: "I want to suppress excess properties, the problem is that I'm unable to tell the compiler that these aren't excess properties, they are the properties of a proper subtype."  Since the type system is structural, there's no difference between "excess properties" and "properties that were added to a proper subtype".

Comment: @jcalz Right, by "any literal will pass" I mean any literal that has `A`'s properties, which is technically an `A` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR TS4.9+**

There is now a [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) which lets you check a value against a type without widening the value to that type.  The new version of this answer therefore looks like:

```
interface A {
    a: string;
}
interface APlus extends A {
    [k: string]: unknown;
}

const bad = { a: 123 } satisfies APlus; // error
// ---------> ~ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
// const bad: { a: number; }

const good = { a: "", b: "" } satisfies APlus; // okay
// const good: { a: string; b: string;}
```

Here `bad` is in error because its `a` property is the wrong type.  And `good` matches `APlus` (which is `A` explicitly allowing excess properties) but its type is still `{a: string, b: string}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8tRJZEVUAFAGwFdjkIAPSCAAmvdNjzIA2gGsipciAoBdIlxAyQAewDuIGvSwItIUsgBGcYcgC8mfEQCMAJgDMyWiThhgxGMAgxTh4qZAB6ML4oKC0oLAjkAFpklJSAPmQAP2QAFQBPAAcUAHIQLgBbc2hi5F9kbTB8YmJgChA4cw4UMC1kMEKShUpigDp4yONTRsthIgwHeoqqqFDDSbMKLS1rO3nCZAAiA4AaCyIjjy8fPwCg7mJQhK0ZODzx5HXGze25haGlULmeRkShUWhAA)

---

**ANSWER FOR TS4.8-**

Update: the main issue here seems to be that TypeScript does not have a "widening only assertion operator" or an "inline type annotation operator" (e.g., `return {a: 123} op A` should fail but `return {a: "", b: ""} op A` should succeed).  There is an [open suggestion for one, see microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) but there's no real movement there.  If you want to see this happen you might want to go to that issue and give it a  and/or describe your use case if it's more compelling than what's already there.  In the absence of an explicit type operator for this, there are strategies and workarounds available.

---

It sounds like you are already aware of the most common options for dealing with this, but you don't like any of them.  I have a few other things you can try, but if your restrictions are:

- no changes to your type definitions or annotations
- no changes to the emitted runtime code
- no [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

then your options are limited indeed and you might not find any answer satisfying.

---

Background on what's happening:

Object literals are an interesting exception to TypeScript's normal extendible object types.  In general, object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  A type definition like `{a: string}` only requires that a value must have a set of known properties.  It does not require that a value must *lack unknown properties*.  So an object `{a: "", b: 123, c: true}` is a perfectly valid value of type `{a: string}`, because it has an `a` property whose value is assignable to `string`.  So it seems that there should be nothing with your code; your `a` is indeed a valid `A`, with or without context.

But of course the compiler complains.  That's because you've assigned a fresh object literal to a variable annotated with a type with fewer known properties than the object literal has.  And thus it runs afoul of [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), where object types are treated as exact.  You can read [the pull request implementing this feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823) and the [rationale for doing this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755).  Those issues also detail the suggested workarounds for situations in which the excess property checking is undesired.

---

You've already mentioned making a helper function (e.g., `return is<A>({...})`), assigning to an intermediate variable (e.g., `const ret = {...}; return ret;`), and using a type assertion (e.g., `return {...} as A`).  Here are the other options as I see them:

- Add an index signature you your `A` type so that it is explicitly open:

  ```
    interface A {
      a: string;
      [k: string]: unknown; // any other property is fine
    }

    const a: A = {  a: "", b: "" }; // okay now
  ```
- Turn off excess property checking entirely with [the `--suppressExcessPropertyErrors` compiler option](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options) (I don't really recommend this because it is such a wide-ranging change)
- Use a [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) like `A | B` instead of `A` when annotating the type corresponding to the object literal:

  ```
    const a: A | B = { a: "", b: ""  }; // okay now
  ```

  Since `B` is a subtype of `A`, the type `A | B` is structurally equivalent to `A`, so you can use it in place of `A` just about anywhere:

  ```
    const foo = (): A | B => { ... } // your impl here
    function onlyAcceptA(a: A) { }
    onlyAcceptA(foo()); // okay
  ```
- use a type assertion just on the extra property, which requires using a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

  ```
     const a: A = { a: "", ["b" as string]: "" }; // okay
  ```

  That really isn't any less type safe, but it does end up generating slightly different JavaScript (`{a: "", ["b"]: ""}`), assuming you are targeting a version of JavaScript that supports computed property names.

Everything else I can think of just changes your runtime code more, so I'll stop there.

---

Anyway, hope that gives you some ideas. Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5GFgBUCe6kG8BYAKCSQEtgAXCAJwDMFkBBAksskALiSitsoBzANzsOAbQDWPPgOCCAujwCuwScAD2Ad2DCkAen1IQwbEg1UAFnSQxaG9LSpnyUJPUoQxAXxJjKNAxMSABCSBAAHjTAACZurESkHABGMvxCPn5J8BrAfMY8rAC8bEmcPABEFQA0YmSpSFU+eobmkiBmmlpZZDl5VO4aGkglABQAlIUjAHylHBT0SKMAsiBWAHS0JjEaYBNIADxIAAzrAKzjc-NItBBUyrTAV9cFjTV11w1NZRy+P97hAA2UGQiRet3uj2e124bw+ZD+80RSD+fxIoEgsGCAFVgORclcAnRGIgkAkPrDZEJREk0UkiUFSWFItE4mToQ0qfJMsQxH18rDWAAfUIjaGwqq1H5fCrNAxGDTtTraHpIfkDehDMUTKYisJFWZgjjkRYrNaWTbbXb7I6nC7QsgQh5PI0vCXvH7zGXwlEfAEQYGgn1OqGumGVWWe33-HlieiqeBUfFPXKA7DMeCIGBUZijQWXfDRsip9OZiDZ3OajQTcYtBVKrJ0jHQOCk5hQEFOACiUS2AAV7DB2wBldLyUr+ajE4Lkn6UsciWP0qeM5DMqIYNmzr1pOSCJe9XICqYlMPuqXzcQVZIVYxuLmKCNy1qKjpILokOkkIA)

Comment: Thanks so much for such a comprehensive response! I don't believe "no changes to your type definitions or annotations" was one of my restrictions, it very well may be that I'm approaching this too much from a classic OOP perspective. The other solutions you brought up aren't really scalable to multiple properties & multiple subtypes, or ruin DRY. Index signature drops semantic value. Union type should be unnecessary since I'm repeating the A B relationship. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: "I don't believe "no changes to your type definitions or annotations" was one of my restrictions". Sure, but then "Union type should be unnecessary since I'm repeating the A B relationship" implies that or something very close.

Comment: updated answer with link to [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) which might correspond to what you mean by "specify an object literal's type".  Of course, that's just a feature *request*, not an existing feature you can use.

Comment: Ah thanks for the proposal link, that's exactly what I'm looking for. A type hint for object literals, something equivalent to `{...} as T` but that fails if `{...}` is not a `T` as opposed to the behavior of `as`. `as T` is the closest thing I have, so I was wondering if there was an equivalent annotation that *additionally* throws an error if it's not a `T`. I'll probably go with the identity function `is` above since it's syntactically closest to what I want, but thank you for listing all my options.

Comment: I've also added one more usecase to my post, which is passing in object literals as parameters.

Comment: @jcalz this is a thorough answer and the reference is useful. Following the linked issue I can see that [Microsoft have actually added the `satisfies` keyword](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#satisfies) and it's available in current TypeScript versions. Would you be willing to update the answer to mention that please?