# A type-safe "as" for inline object construction in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tsx

In TypeScript I often need an object to be of a certain type, as the inferred type doesn't produce the desired results -- this happens with type hierarchies with a base class, or when intermediates are used to store a value.

I've been using "as" for this, but it's not type-safe, for example, given:

```
interface SomeType {
  some: integer
}
```

Then:

```
{ some: 123 } as SomeType // this passes
{ wrong: "abc" } as SomeType // but this also passes
```

If I assign to a variable I can get what I want:

```
const a : SomeType = { wrong: "abc" } // fails as desired
```

But in some cases it's inconvenient to use a variable. *Is there an equivalent way to do the type-safe casting as an expression?*

---

For my uses, I've added a simple function that seems to work:

```
export function safeAs<T>(value: T): T {
  return value
}
```

Then:

```
safeAs<SomeType>({ some: 123 }) // this passes
safeAs<SomeType>({ wrong: "abc" }) // this fails, as wanted
```

But it feels that this is a fundamental need and I assume I'm missing some syntax that would already do this.

Note: I need this to work in TSX (react) files, which I know sometimes impinges on generic/type syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you specify an object literal's type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725802/can-you-specify-an-object-literals-type-in-typescript)

Comment: @jonrsharpe While I think the linked TypeScript issues and context covers the same area, I think my situation I think is more about the inferred type check, as opposed to the excess property check. I'm not sure.

Comment: Given that you've ended up writing the same implementation as `is`/`asType` and describe the same problem, I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to draw. But if you don't know what your question is it'll be hard to answer it!

Comment: Using `as` is always unsafe, it's basically making typescript think that your variable is of a different type as inferred.

Comment: @MikeS. the OP seems to be aware of that, they included an example showing exactly how it fails and wrote _"I've been using "as" for this, but it's not type-safe"_.

Comment: The provided code is [throwing an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG8AoZZAZywgC5kQBXTAI2gG5SBfU0hdEJTDI4yALzJiVGvQCMAJgDMyLiMpoa+IsgD0O5GAAWwdQTiVKESnwFDkLcZOQB3KAIDm9AERwWCLypqGthaKHr2jMJGJiIANtTIZhZWQA) telling you to cast to unknown first. You may want to consider using typeguards `func(arg): arg is MyType `

Comment: I faced the exact same issue, even IntelliJ inlines constant expression with an `as` syntax which is very dangerous as you now can pass basically any property to the object. I ended up always defining a typed `const` before any return, but that just feels very chatty.

Answer (score 2):

This has been addressed in TS version 4.9, with the introduction of the [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator.

```
const t1 = { some: 123, foo: 0 } as SomeType; // this passes :(
const t2 = { some: 123, foo: 0 } satisfies SomeType; // errors on extra property
const t3 = { some: "123" } satisfies SomeType; // errors on wrong type
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG8AoZC5AZywgC5kQBXTAI2gG5SBfU0hdCCphkYAIzIAvMmLVaDMQCYAzABpkMdOgYAGZN2RwqaWviIdkAekuiAFsGMEjVCMboAKfoOGjFUmXLYCirqmtrIegZUcGAOMMCuJthmEBbWyNBQ6FDGghkAHmBQcMgEWURQYHheQiJgyv6yNEHIAERKyq361DFxCcYYyYSpVjaZ2bkgyADuWSAA5qLDpEA)

See [new Typescript "satisfies" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909490/new-typescript-satisfies-operator)