# new Typescript "satisfies" operator

Tags: typescript

Here is an example from the [official announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) about the `satisfies` operator :

```
type Colors = "red" | "green" | "blue";

// Ensure that we have exactly the keys from 'Colors'.
const favoriteColors = {
    "red": "yes",
    "green": false,
    "blue": "kinda",
    "platypus": false
//  ~~~~~~~~~~ error - "platypus" was never listed in 'Colors'.
} satisfies Record<Colors, unknown>;
```

What does it bring more than just:

```
type Colors = "red" | "green" | "blue";

// Ensure that we have exactly the keys from 'Colors'.
const favoriteColors: Record<Colors, unknown> = {
    "red": "yes",
    "green": false,
    "blue": "kinda",
    "platypus": false
//  ~~~~~~~~~~ error - "platypus" was never listed in 'Colors'.
};
```

In each case the `platypus` raises an error because the Colors type only has `red`, `green`, or `blue`.

Answer (score 59):

The difference is what you can do with `favoriteColors` after you define it.

With `satisfies`, the actual type of the assigned object literal is used as the type of  `favoriteColors`, the information about what keys and values it contains is preserved (the type of the object literal is just checked against the type it's supposed to satisfy).

```
// Ensure that we have exactly the keys from 'Colors'.
const favoriteColors = {
    "red": "yes",
    "green": false,
    "blue": "kinda",
} satisfies Record<Colors, unknown>;
favoriteColors.blue.toUpperCase() //ok it's a string
favoriteColors.green.toUpperCase() // error, it's a boolean
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QLxQETIgE2ygB8cBzPCAOyNOwCMEBXCbAbgCgOB6bqAUSqomeKMAAWAQ2BQA7tCkA3aBAAekgMbAEIMeOgBrCCHQAzZHAC2UAOTwkaGwDoOGuEJmnJilAEtgEPYo6FgA3hxQkTh4hABcOCAQqNgANBFR2BQQ1NjxXgioEGlROIwsuTgGvlT4kqkcAL5QqNK+qKa+SVAAShBuyPgAPEFoKVBMVAZUcLJUAHycXj7I-oGIwU5lEE7AcACqYJDIMJKFABQAlFC8cAZQ-jboks3AK1RkHEt+ASOoTlnUHb7Q4QY6nCCXa58UEWZBjB5PKD0OCICCSKhQLhAA)

Without `satisfies`, the type of accessing the property of `favoriteColors` will be `unknown` since the type of `favoriteColors` will be `Record<Colors, unknown>` as declared in the annotation. The information from the object literal is lost.

```
// Ensure that we have exactly the keys from 'Colors'.
const favoriteColors: Record<Colors, unknown> = {
    "red": "yes",
    "green": false,
    "blue": "kinda",
};

favoriteColors.blue.toUpperCase() // error, favoriteColors.blue is unknown
favoriteColors.green.toUpperCase() // error, favoriteColors.green is unknown
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QLxQETIgE2ygB8cBzPCAOyNOwCMEBXCbAbgCgOB6bqAUSqomeKMAAWAQ2BQA7tCkA3aBAAekgMbAEIMeOgBrCCHQAzZHAC2UAOTwkaGwDoOGuEJmnJilAEtgEPYoqABcUABKEG7I+AA8QWgANFBMVAZUcLJUAHyYUADeHFDFOHiEYdggEKjYiUUl2BQQ1NhhXgioEHUlOIwsrTgGvlT4krUcAL6cHF4+yP6BiMFOfRBOwHAAqmCQyDCSnQAUAJRQvFAQyBbIybN+AQmoK8zQvuip6ZlUM973iw5PJrUdZbHaXfZHU7nS7XW6-eYPJZoJxAqhQN4pNIZLJAA)

Comment: Also, like `as`, it can be used in an expression, one does not need to declare a variable for it.

Comment: @Bergi This is especially useful for frameworks like Vue that use object literals a lot.

Comment: looks like an improper union to me. if you know green -> bool it's a distinct type

Comment: But unlike `as`, it is type-safe.