# why is Typescript 4.9's "satisfies" operator necessary to type objects with specified set of properties?

Tags: typescript

The [examples for the new `satisfies` operator in Typescript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton) include one to "ensure that an object has all the keys of some type, but no more:

```
type Colors = "red" | "green" | "blue";

// Ensure that we have exactly the keys from 'Colors'.
const favoriteColors = {
    "red": "yes",
    "green": false,
    "blue": "kinda",
    "platypus": false
//  ~~~~~~~~~~ error - "platypus" was never listed in 'Colors'.
} satisfies Record<Colors, unknown>;

// All the information about the 'red', 'green', and 'blue' properties are retained.
const g: boolean = favoriteColors.green;
```

Why is the `satisfies` operator necessary there? It seems you can already do this, right? Just type your object as usual:

```
const tooManyColors: Record<Colors, unknown> = {
    "red": "yes",
    "green": false,
    "blue": "kinda",
    "platypus": false
//  ~~~~~~~~~~: Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"platypus"' does not exist in type 'Record<Colors, unknown>'.(2322)
};
```

That same approach also works if you omit a property:

```
const notEnough = {
    "red": "yes",
    "green": false,
} satisfies Record<Colors, unknown>;
//          ~~~~~~: Property 'blue' is missing
```

If my intent is to ensure that my object has exactly those properties specified in `Colors`, is there any reason to use `satisfies` rather than the usual stuff above?

I understand that using `satisfies` is desirable over the usual typing approach above because it'll allow TS to infer the types of the individual properties, but it doesn't seem necessary for ensuring the *presence or absence* of properties. Am I missing something?

Comment: The answer to this is there on the page you linked to: *"But we now have an undesirable error here - 'palette.red' "could" be a string."* It has also already been answered on Stack Overflow: [new Typescript "satisfies" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909490/new-typescript-satisfies-operator)

Comment: `satisfies` does not alter the automatic exact type which isn't a `Record<Color, unknown>`, it's a `{ 'red': 'yes', green: false, ... }`. Specifying it as `Record` means you loose information.

Comment: So, it sounds like the answer to my question -- if *the only thing* one is interested in is the presence or absence of properties, the usual typing does the same thing as `satisfies`.