# Is it possible to create a Partial like util which does not lose information about existing properties

Tags: typescript

How to make TypeScript know when creating `comprehensiveDict` that all the keys have been defined ?

If I drop the type annotation on `partialDict` and use `as const`, it will work, but I want to ensure when creating `partialDict` that only properly formed entries are used, and that the keys are valid `Word`s.

```
type Word = "good" | "bad" | "ok";
type Dict = {
  [key in Word]: {
    fr: string;
  };
};

const partialDict: Partial<Dict> = {
  ok: { fr: "moyen" },
  good: { fr: "bon" },
} as const;

const comprehensiveDict: Dict = {
  ...partialDict,
  bad: { fr: "mauvais" },
};
```

It seems to me that we cannot at the same type create an object and infer the keys of this object in the type annotation, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909490/new-typescript-satisfies-operator

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m33e2m) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer (but I might also find a relevant duplicate); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks