# Simpler way to check literal object type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, object-literal

I want to `Object.assign` to an object of a known type, a set of properties from an object literal that should be of the same type. Is there a cleaner way to do this in TypeScript, without actually calling an identity function, or creating a separate variable, as suggested in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456105/how-can-i-specify-a-typed-object-literal-in-typescript)?

```js
type Person = {
  first?: string;
  last?: string;
}

// Overkill, actually generates code to call a function
function check<T>(value: T): T { return value; }

const dude: Person = {
  first: 'Mike',
};

Object.assign(dude, check<Person>({  // <- trying not to call a function
  last: 'Johnson',
  age: 27,  // <-- should be flagged as unknown property
}));
```

TL;DR - looking for a way to type check an object literal directly.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSgDMBLJYAfgC4pFh5jUBzAbnygBsBDWqmuhlrgC+uXAGM0tKABMArtIjU4SNJhxsSZagHIAssQDWEbQBphrXAHkARgCsIY4ADpuiYo1QAeZSlQnYCL4AfAAUcgr+eARctDoAUsgAFqi+pmycjIpQAEwA7GZCAJQWuEA) maybe?  I'll write it up if that works for you; otherwise please specify how it fails to meet your needs.  Good luck.

Comment: @jcalz: that's a neat solution, would upvote if it were an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a "perfect" solution to this that works in all circumstances.  Most of the mechanisms that convince the compiler to perform the type checking you want are also accompanied by some added runtime code (such as a new intermediate variable assignment, or calling an identity function), which you've said you don't want.

---

One problem is that TypeScript doesn't have inline type annotations.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) and [microsoft/TypeScript#13208](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13208) for discussion.)  You'd like to be able to ask the compiler to *verify* that an expression `{...}` is of type `Person`, and have the compiler complain if it cannot be verified.  The closest operator we have in TypeScript is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) of the form `{...} as Person`.  But this *tells* the compiler that the expression `{...}` is of the type `Person`; you want to *ask*.

---

Even if we had an inline annotation operator, there's another problem: object types in TypeScript are not *exact*. (See [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for discussion.)  Object types in TypeScript are *open* in that you can add more properties to them without breaking compatibility.  If you have an object of type `Person`, you know something about its `first` and `last` properties, but you really don't know anything about any other properties.  Just because the definition of `Person` doesn't mention an `age` property, it *does not mean* that an object of type `Person` cannot have an `age` property.  There could well be an interface like this:

```
interface AgedPerson extends Person {
  age: number;
}
```

The [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) nature of the TypeScript type system means that `{last: "Johnson", age: 27}` is a valid `AgedPerson` even if you don't declare it as such (and even if `AgedPerson` is not defined).  And since `AgedPerson` is a valid subtype of `Person`, then `{last: "Johnson", age: 27}` is a valid `Person` also.

Now, when people use object literals like `{last: "Johnson", age: 27}` they usually don't intend to add such extra properties, so TypeScript has a feature called [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) which treats object literals as if they were of exact types and complains if you add unknown properties.  This feature is useful, but it's very easy to circumvent.  So it's important to mention that if you refactor your code at all, the warning about `age` being an excess property might disappear:

```
const ageDude = { last: 'Johnson', age: 27 };
const personDude: Person = ageDude; // no error
```

---

That being said, for the particular example you gave, the solution I'd recommend would be:

```
Object.assign<Person, Person>(dude, {
  last: 'Johnson',
  age: 27, // error
});
```

Here you are manually specifying the generic type parameters on the call to `Object.assign`, where the first type parameter corresponds to the type of the first function argument, and the second type parameter corresponds to the type of the second function argument.  You want the compiler to treat both of those as `Person`, so you should write `Object.assign<Person, Person>(...)`.  And the expected excess property error appears.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSgDMBLJYAfgC4pFh5jUBzAbnygBsBDWqmuhlrgC+uXAGM0tKABMArtIjU4SNJhxsSZagHIAssQDWEbQBphrXA2AJCnMdACCjCNOUp0EAB7XU0xLAR3dQJOZ2pUWQBbACMEVhFxSWAoUIgAEXloLGwObmAdAClkAAtUd1MUsKgAJgB2KCFWCTLkyBVUDIUlQNUsVM6IZigAemGoVGQoBHhkeFEAeWiAKwgxYAA6bkRiRlQAHjc0EwD2gD4ACjkFY7wCLlpCkrK0UzZU6jqzIQBKC3wgA)